# JQM duplicated tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to append all `data-role=header` pages an icon menu to the left, but it's duplicating in the right, can someone give me an explanation? the `html()` works but the header are not resizing with the icon.

```
var header = '<a href="#left-panel" id="panel-left" data-icon="carat-r" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-bullets ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline"></a>';
```

updated code: the button in the header is missing.

```
$(document).one('pagebeforecreate', function () {
    $.mobile.pageContainer.prepend(panel);
    $("[data-role=panel]").enhanceWithin();
    $("#left-panel").panel();
    /* search for button and header in active page only*/
    var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
    if( $("#panel-left", activePage).length === 0 ) {
    $("[data-role=header]", activePage).append(header);
    }
});
```

[image: the image describe itself]
[image]

Comment: How many pages have you got on your document? I think the code is executing more than once and is adding several icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

Since you're using *Single Page Model* and you *data-prefetch* external links, `getActivePage` will return first page in DOM. Hence, *activePage* should be the page being created. Place the below code outside the one you're using to append *External Panel* dynamically.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', function (e) {
  var activePage = $(e.target);
    if ($("#panel-left", activePage).length === 0) {
        $("[data-role=header]", activePage).append(header);
    }
});
```

---

You need to check first whether the button is already appended, as `pagebeforecreate` fires on every page being created.

### Update

On `pagecreate`, check if current page has no button in header and append it.

```
var header = '<a href="#left-panel" id="panel-left" data-icon="carat-r" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-bullets ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-inline"></a>';

$(document).one('pagebeforecreate', function () {
    /* append External panel once */
    $.mobile.pageContainer.prepend(panel);
    $("#left-panel").panel();
    /* append button on pagecreate */
    $(document).on('pagecreate', function () {
        var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
        if ($("#panel-left", activePage).length === 0) {
            $("[data-role=header]", activePage).append(header);
        }
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/8X8Xu/)**

Comment: It's because I have more than one page and gives me the duplicated icons?

Comment: @fsi yes, and append it to first page's header. That's why you need yo append button to active page.

Comment: @fsi can you update your question with code used, JQM version?

Comment: Check the cache, is usual when testing the site on the phone.

Comment: @fsi you are appending external panel once as well as button. You need to append button on each page create in a separate function or inside the function you're using now, only button not panel. I'm using iphone it's difficult to update my code now.

Comment: Ok, but the button still missing, I've checked other browsers(FF, OPERA) and they are showing, just on mobile that are not working.

Comment: @fsi it should work properly now, check updated code and demo. It was a mistake using `pagebeforecreate` to append buttons. Use `pagecreate` instead.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48483/discussion-between-omar-and-fsi)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is adding `header` to every `[data-role=header]` on every `pagebeforecreate` event, so maybe it is duplicating code. Try this:

```
$(document).one('pagebeforecreate', function () {
    $(this).find("[data-role=header]").append(header);
});
```